# Installing TideSDK 1.3.1 Beta in Mac OS X

Tags: tidesdk

I'm trying to follow the instructions in the Getting Started guide for the Hello World sample application for the TideSDK 1.3.1 beta on OS X Mavericks (version 10.9). When I try to do Step 4 and import the Hello World application into the TideSDK Developer, I get the error message "You are importing a desktop project, but no Desktop SDK versions exist on your system". Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong, or where the installation guide is off? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten that the Apple unzip utility creates an extra directory with the same name as the zip file. When I took the contents out of that directory and put them directly in Users/[myName]/Library/Application Support/TideSDK, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

to install the SDK do this.

Unzip the SDK inside your HD > Users > [You user folder] > Library > Application Support > TideSDK